# Determine When SpriteNode Is Landed On A Rectangle SpriteNode

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game where there are clouds moving, and I want it so the clouds will fade away when the character lands on it.  However, when I put the code, it fades away if the character goes around it and hits the bottom or the side of the cloud while it is still falling.  Here is the code I have for detecting when the character and cloud have hit.

Is there anyway to determine when the character has landed on top of the cloud so it does not fade the cloud away if it hits it from the bottom or side while it is falling?

Here is code for declaring the objects:

```
    Person.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    Person.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width / 25, self.frame.size.height / 16.25)
    Person.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Person.size)
    Person.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    Person.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    Person.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    Person.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    Person.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    Person.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    Person.zPosition = 5
    Person.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.PersonCategory.rawValue
    Person.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.CloudCategory.rawValue
    Person.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) * 1.7)
    self.addChild(Person)


    Cloud = SKSpriteNode(texture: NormalCloudTexture)
    Cloud.zPosition = 7
    Cloud.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    Cloud.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Cloud.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    Cloud.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width / 8.05, self.frame.size.height / 40)
    Cloud.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Cloud.size)
    Cloud.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    Cloud.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    Cloud.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    Cloud.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) / 7.60)
    addChild(Cloud)
```

Here is code for when the objects have hit:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)
{


    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    switch(contactMask)
    {
    case BodyType.PersonCategory.rawValue | BodyType.CloudCategory.rawValue:
        JumpContact = true
        let CheckDelay = delay(0.055)
            {

                    //cloud fades away here

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not done it, but i have an idea. :)

I think you should do:
Track contact position with ***contactPoint*** property and then check if it is not touching x position of the cloud lower then few points from the top.

I hope it helps you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your recommendation!  I decided to fool around, here is what you do guys!

```
//put like a few millisecond delay here, forgot it

 if (Person.physicsBody?.velocity.dy == 0){//this means the person has stopped moving since it landed
                    //cloud fades away
                }
```